# Links in Magento Subfolder store go back to main index.php file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

- I created a new folder /wholesale/
- I copied index.php and htaccess file to that folder
- I changed index.php to use the root files =>

code

```
$compilerConfig = '/home/shop_production/htdocs/includes/config.php';
$mageFilename = '/home/shop_production/htdocs/app/Mage.php';
require '/home/shop_production/htdocs/app/Mage.php';

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? 

$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'wholesale';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

Mage::run('wholesale', 'website');
```

- I created a new root category in magento and changed the Base Url in Magento
- I created a new home in CMS - Pages
- I also created shortcuts to all folders in the root directory inside of the wholesale directory (eg. app, includes, js, lib, media, skin, var)

**=> my homepage is showing the correct page and design at mydomain.com/wholesale/**

But as soon as I click on any link, it gives me the following error:

```
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations Trace:
#0 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /home/shop_production/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /home/shop_production/htdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('en_kigu', 'store')
#4 {main}
```

It looks like it's using the wrong index.php and therefor the wrong "Mage::run" command?

- I already flushed the cache and emptied the core_url_rewrite file in sql and reindexed everything.

What else can I do?